# How to get the latest 2 rows ( PostgreSQL )

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I need your help to modify a query to accomplish the requirement.

According to the GATHER_TIME, I want to show the VALUE of the NAMEs.
The query runs every 1 minute, and it should get 2 rows all the time. 
In case, there is no data at that time, it should get the past( 1 minute earlier ) data for the Name.

Here, specific requirement is that I should not consider seconds value in Timestamp value(GATHER_TIME).

I tried to make a query like below.
It only gets the latest data.

Can you help me out?

## Query

```
select NAME,sum(VALUE)
FROM TestTable
WHERE substring(to_char(gather_time,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),1,16) IN ( SELECT MAX(substring(to_char(gather_time,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),1,16)) FROM TestTable )
GROUP BY NAME
```

## Table Data

```
NAME    COL1   COL2    GATHER_TIME         VALUE
------------------------------------------------
first   prince PQ1     2015-12-29 13:10:33 11
first   prince PQ2     2015-12-29 13:10:33 14
first   prince PQ3     2015-12-29 13:10:33 18
first   prince PQ4     2015-12-29 13:10:33 19
second  prince TT1     2015-12-29 13:10:59 20
second  prince TT2     2015-12-29 13:10:59 29
second  prince TT3     2015-12-29 13:10:59 43
first   prince PQ1     2015-12-29 13:11:37 71
first   prince PQ2     2015-12-29 13:11:37 74
first   prince PQ3     2015-12-29 13:11:37 78
first   prince PQ4     2015-12-29 13:11:37 79
```

## Required result

```
@ Query time: 2015-12-29 13:10:59
first       62
second      92

@ Query time: 2015-12-29 13:11:59
first       302
second      92
```

## Added:

Sorry. I should have put more detail test data. Updated it.

## If two columns are used in GROUP BY:: ( Need to be verified )

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name,col1,gather_time) name,col1,SUM(value) 
FROM test_table
GROUP BY name,col1,gather_time
ORDER BY gather_time DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: use `order by gather_time` with `limit 2` ,  I think that will give u result as u want

Comment: question description is not correct ; 2 sample statements should have consistent `ORDER`; for `2015-12-29 13:10:59` Query time you have `ASC`  order, but for query time `2015-12-29 13:11:59` you have `DESC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- DDL
CREATE TABLE test_table(
  name TEXT,
  col2 TEXT,
  gather_time TIMESTAMP,
  value INTEGER
);

--sample data
INSERT INTO test_table  VALUES
  ('first','PQ1','2015-12-29 13:10:33'::TIMESTAMP, 11),
  ('first','PQ2','2015-12-29 13:10:33'::TIMESTAMP, 14),
  ('first','PQ3','2015-12-29 13:10:33'::TIMESTAMP, 18),
  ('first','PQ4','2015-12-29 13:10:33'::TIMESTAMP, 19),
  ('second','TT1','2015-12-29 13:10:59'::TIMESTAMP, 20),
  ('second','TT2','2015-12-29 13:10:59'::TIMESTAMP, 29),
  ('second','TT3','2015-12-29 13:10:59'::TIMESTAMP, 43),
  ('first','PQ1','2015-12-29 13:11:37'::TIMESTAMP, 71),
  ('first','PQ2','2015-12-29 13:11:37'::TIMESTAMP, 74),
  ('first','PQ3','2015-12-29 13:11:37'::TIMESTAMP, 78),
  ('first','PQ4','2015-12-29 13:11:37'::TIMESTAMP, 79);

--query to run every minute
SELECT name,SUM(value) FROM test_table
  WHERE gather_time <= now()
  GROUP BY name,gather_time
  ORDER BY gather_time DESC
  LIMIT 2;
```

OR using function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_2latest_agg_rows(qtime timestamp) 
  RETURNS TABLE (
    order_name TEXT,
    sum_value BIGINT
 ) AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
  SELECT name as order_name,SUM(value) as agg_result FROM test_table
  WHERE gather_time <= qtime::TIMESTAMP
  GROUP BY name,gather_time
  ORDER BY gather_time DESC
  LIMIT 2;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

--sample run
SELECT * FROM get_2latest_agg_rows('2015-12-29 13:11:59'::TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated the test data. Can you advise me again?

Comment: Oh. Wonderful!. I'm going to go over DISTINCT ON keyword. Thank you so much again.

Comment: If two columns should be used in GROUP BY, the query I put in question makes sense?

Comment: What if there is another value in NAME column such as 'third','fourth'? Do we have to increase LIMIT value? LIMIT keyword is mandatory in this query?

Comment: The `DISTINCT` is unnecessary, given you have `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

What if you will sort by gather_time and use limit 2 to get the latest 2 rows?
Will that fit the requirments?

`select NAME,sum(VALUE)
 FROM TestTable
 ORDER BY gather_time DESC
 LIMIT 2;`

Comment: You can't use an aggregate function (`SUM`) unless it's the only column returned, or you include `GROUP BY`.